# Creating word pairs from phrases

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Is there any way to get the possible word pairs from word phrases? I have a list of word phrases and I need to find all the possible word pair combinations from it. I can normally tokenize the phrases to get the words and then find all the possible pairs. But if I want to have some pair which consists of one phrase and one word of another phrase then is it possible to do it?
For example:
The list of phrases can be something as

```
['influenza virus', 'elderberry liquid extract', 'previous study', 'elderberry fruit', 'berry good']
```

The possible pairs should also contain these

```
[(influenza virus,elderberry),(influenza virus, liquid),(influenza virus, extract).....]
```

Is there any way to do this? I have done the word pairings for individual words. I am looking for something that can do the above.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = []
for item1 in a:
    for item2 in a:
        if item1!=item2:
            for part2 in item2.split(' '):
                b.append((item1, part2))
print(b)
```

output:

```
[('influenza virus', 'elderberry'), ('influenza virus', 'liquid'), ('influenza virus', 'extract'), ('influenza virus', 'previous'), ('influenza virus', 'study'), ('influenza virus', 'elderberry'), ('influenza virus', 'fruit'), ('influenza virus', 'berry'), ('influenza virus', 'good'), ('elderberry liquid extract', 'influenza')...
```